# How to Disable a CSS File Before Loading the Site

Tags: html, css

The title looks confusing, but I will explain it.

I am trying to customize an old forum.
I write userStyle, upload it to the Greasyfork, then download and apply it through TamperMonkey.

The forum is super old, meaning its html and css are old and redundant in all sorts of way.
Therefore I decided to disable its css file and write my own one.
The problem is... at the time being, the old css and new css would be applied at the same time.

**What I want the website/broswer to do:**

1. load its css file //or just never load it
2. disable old css file
3. load custom css file

**What is actually happening at the moment:**

1. load both old and custom css file
2. disable old css file

Basically, the old css is red and the custom one is blue, the old one has lots of "!important".
Everytime I refresh the site it will be like chaos for 2 sec(my ping is ~200ms btw), and it hurts me... mentally.

Therefore I want that when I refresh the website, **it does not load old css**.
The code for removing old css file is following.

```
// Remove old css file that has "static" in the href attribute using jQuery
$('link[href*="static"]').remove()
```

If you want more info, please feel free to ask.
Many thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To disable CSS, just make it as comment in CSS import section, like this:

```html
...
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" src="/path/to/old.css" /> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" src="/path/to/custom.css" />
...
```

With jQuery:

```js
$('link[rel="stylesheet"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" src="/path/to/custom.css" />');
```

Comment: I can not just comment out a line... I do not have the direct access to html file, that is why i am using jquery to .remove() them.